# About resonance in the (undamped) harmonic oscillator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

Consider the undamped harmonic oscillator $x''(t) + \omega_0^2 x(t) = A cos(\omega t)$.
The general (real) solution of the homogenous equation is given by $x_h(t) = a cos(\omega_0 t) + b sin(\omega_0 t)$. For the inhomogeneous we get a particular solution $x_p(t) = \frac{A}{2 \omega} t sin(\omega t)$ (via the Ansatz $x_p(t) = c t sin (\omega t)$). Why do we say that the forcing term is 'resonant' if $\omega = \omega_0$? Is it meant that the solution simply tends in this case to infinity for $t \to \infty$?

What is the difference if we consider the damped oscillator $x''(t) + r x' + \omega_0^2 x(t) = A cos(\omega t)$? I suppose that in this case $x(t)$ gets maximal if $\omega = \omega_0$. Is this correct and what more could one say about resonance here?

Comment: In your DE for the undamped driven oscillator, you consider only a oscillator driven at its natural frequency. Is this intentional? If you want to talk about resonance, it might be useful to look at the case where the frequency of the driving force is free to take any value.

Comment: ah of course, I edited..

Comment: 2 more notes: the $\omega_0$ in the damped case is not actually the natural frequency of the oscillator. It's nothing you need to change, but it might be good to keep in mind. Also, you might want to double check your solution for the edited Differential equation. The ansatz you used only works when $\omega=\omega_0$.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the Fourier transform you get
$$(\omega_{0}^{2}-\Omega^{2})\hat{x}(\Omega)=\pi{A}(\delta(\Omega-\omega)+\delta(\Omega+\omega))$$
$$\hat{x}(\Omega)=\frac{A\pi(\delta(\Omega-\omega)+\delta(\Omega+\omega))}{(\omega_{0}^{2}-\Omega^{2})}$$
$$x(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\hat{x}(\Omega)e^{i\Omega{t}}d\Omega=\frac{A\cos(\omega{t})}{\omega_{0}^{2}-\omega^{2}}$$
When $\omega_{0}\rightarrow\omega$ solution diverges, in physics you say it's a resonance.

Comment: If you haven't heard about FT, then take the ansatz $x_{p}(t)=c\cos(\Omega{t})$. After substitution you have $c(\omega_{0}^{2}-\Omega^{2})\cos(\Omega{t})=A\cos(\omega{t})$. So you conclude that $\Omega=\omega$ and $c=\frac{A}{\omega_{0}^{2}-\omega^{2}}$, hence $y_{p}=\frac{A\cos(\omega{t})}{\omega_{0}^{2}-\omega^{2}}$. As above.

Answer (score 0):

In the whole below, it is supposed that $\omega_0\neq 0$ .
$$\text{FIRST PART}$$
$$x''(t) + \omega_0^2 x(t) = A \cos(\omega t)$$

Case $\omega_0\neq \omega$ :

$x_p(t)=c \cos(\omega t) \quad\to\quad c=\frac{A}{\omega_0^2-\omega^2}$
$$x(t)=\frac{A}{\omega_0^2-\omega^2}\cos(\omega t)+a\sin(\omega t)+b\cos(\omega t)$$

Case $\omega_0= \omega$ :

$x_p(t)=c t\sin(\omega_0 t) \quad\to\quad c=\frac{A}{2\omega_0^2}$
$$x(t)=\frac{A}{2\omega_0^2}\sin(\omega_0 t)+a\sin(\omega_0 t)+b\cos(\omega_0 t)$$

$$\text{SECOND PART}$$
$$x''(t) +r x'+ \omega_0^2 x(t) = A \cos(\omega t)$$
They are six cases to consider :

(1) : $\omega_0\neq \omega \quad$ and $\quad r^2-4\omega_0^2>0$

(2) : $\omega_0\neq \omega\quad$ and $\quad r^2-4\omega_0^2=0$

(3) : $\omega_0\neq \omega\quad$ and $\quad r^2-4\omega_0^2<0$

(4) : $\omega_0= \omega\quad$ and $\quad r^2-4\omega_0^2>0$

(5) : $\omega_0= \omega\quad$ and $\quad r^2-4\omega_0^2=0$

(6) : $\omega_0= \omega\quad$ and $\quad r^2-4\omega_0^2<0$

The three first cases are more complicated to solve (but possible, of course).

For the three last cases (with $\omega_0=\omega$) the solution is :

Case (4) : 
$$x(t)=\frac{A}{r\omega_0}\sin(\omega_0 t)
+a\,\exp\left(\left(\sqrt{r^2-4\omega_0^2}-r\right) \frac{t}{2}\right)
+b\,\exp\left(\left(-\sqrt{r^2-4\omega_0^2}-r\right) \frac{t}{2}\right)$$

Case (5) : 
$$x(t)=\frac{A}{r\omega_0}\sin(\omega_0 t)
+a\,e^{-\omega_0 t}
+b\,t\,e^{-\omega_0 t}$$

Case (6) :
$$x(t)=\frac{A}{r\omega_0}\sin(\omega_0 t)
+a\,\sin\left(\left(\sqrt{-r^2+4\omega_0^2}-r\right) \frac{t}{2}\right)
+b\,\cos\left(\left(-\sqrt{-r^2+4\omega_0^2}-r\right) \frac{t}{2}\right)$$

Note: the same symbols $a$ and $b$ are used for all cases. This doesn't mean that those constants are equal from one case to another.